# tf:TransformTFToEigen() causes 'TransformTFToEigen' is not a member of 'tf'

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While trying to build dvo_ros package for dense visual SLAM, i was given
'TransformTFToEigen' is not a member of 'tf'
error for the line
tf::TransformTFToEigen(tmp, result);

I have been trying to search around the documentations for tf package but could not find anything on the above function. Have the  function been removed? If so was there a replace for the above function?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/155486/tf:transformtftoeigen()-causes-%27transformtftoeigen%27-is-not-a-member-of-%27tf%27/) by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2014-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This function is part of the "tf_conversions" package, specifically I think it is found in "tf_conversions/tf_eigen.h".

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zenifed](https://answers.ros.org/users/5788/zenifed/) on 2014-04-21**:
Thanks! I found it exactly where you have pointed me to. Hmm everything seems to be in order, what could have the cause of the error above.

**Comment by [tcpu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22431/tcpu/) on 2015-05-14**:
Excuse me.I have met the same probelem as you.I want to know how  you solve the problem.Thank you.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2015-05-14**:
This error occurs when you do not have the above header included in your code.

**Comment by [Soonhac](https://answers.ros.org/users/225/soonhac/) on 2015-08-06**:
I have met the same problem. The header file is included in the code. How can I solve this problem?

**Comment by [Soonhac](https://answers.ros.org/users/225/soonhac/) on 2015-08-12**:
I solved this problem by replacing "TransformTFToEigen" and "TransformEigenToTF" with "transformTFToEigen" and "transformEigenToTF" respectively. Please see https://github.com/tum-vision/dvo/issues/2.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another possible solution from my experiments

Try transformEigenToTF (with the small t instead of capital T).

link: http://answers.ros.org/question/62436/concatenating-relative-transformations-to-obtain-a-global-transformation/

This change to convert to  `transformEigenToTF` has solved the issue in my case. I am using ros indigo on 14.04

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2016-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2